# In Android, when is an Interface called?

Tags: java, android

This is my first attempt at an Android game. I need to draw a path that starts at the center of the screen, and I'm getting the center screen coordinates using `OnGlobalLayoutListener`. In order to pass the center coordinates to my View class I'm using an `Interface`. Now, assuming that the Interface is working, it's passing 0,0 because the drawn path is starting at the upper left of my Relative Layout. I'm getting the correct coordinates because for now I'm passing them to a `TextView` so I can see the coordinates, but they're not getting passed to the View class because the path starts in the upper left, not the center of my Relative Layout. So I guess my question is: **Does the Interface get triggered before `onCreate` completes?** And if so, how can I get the center screen data to the Interface before the Interface is triggered? Can I somehow trigger the Interface after I get the screen data? Here are the classes I'm working with, first the Main Activity:

```
public class Game1 extends Activity implements GBoardValueSetter {
DrawPath dp;
TextView gameScore_TV, gameTime_TV;
private CountDownTimer mainGameCD;
private boolean mainGameTimerHasStarted = false;
private final long mainCDTime = 30 * 1000;
private final long mainCDInterval = 1 * 1000;

// ---GameBoard variables
RelativeLayout root_RL, gBoardInfo_RL, gBoard_RL;
LayoutInflater LayInf = null;
View root_VUE, gBoardInfo_VUE;
LayoutParams root_LP, gBoardInfo_LP, gBoard_LP;
int xScr2Int, yScr2Int, xScrInt, yScrInt, xCenterInt, yCenterInt;
String xCenterStr, yCenterStr, xHStr, yWStr;
float xCenter_FL, yCenter_FL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.cutin, R.anim.cutout);

    root_RL = new RelativeLayout(this);
    root_LP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    root_RL.setId(1);
    root_RL.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    root_RL.setLayoutParams(root_LP);
    setContentView(root_RL);

    createBlankGBoard();
    addDP();
}// --- END onCreate


//--- Interface call
@Override
public void passGBCenterIntValuesInterface(int xC_IInt, int yC_IInt) {
    xC_IInt = xCenterInt;
    yC_IInt = yCenterInt;
    dp.setCenterInt(xC_IInt, yC_IInt);

}//--- END Interface call


public void createBlankGBoard(){
    LayInf = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    gBoardInfo_VUE = LayInf.inflate(R.layout.game1_info, null);
    gBoardInfo_LP = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    gBoardInfo_LP.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    gBoardInfo_VUE.setId(2);
    gBoardInfo_VUE.setLayoutParams(gBoardInfo_LP);
    gameTime_TV = (TextView) gBoardInfo_VUE.findViewById(R.id.game1_timeValue2_TV);
    gameScore_TV = (TextView) gBoardInfo_VUE.findViewById(R.id.game1_scoreValue2_TV);
    root_RL.addView(gBoardInfo_VUE);

    gBoard_RL = new RelativeLayout(this);
    gBoard_LP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    gBoard_LP.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, gBoardInfo_VUE.getId());
    gBoard_LP.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    gBoard_RL.setLayoutParams(gBoard_LP);
    gBoard_RL.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    root_RL.addView(gBoard_RL);
    getGameBoardNumbers();
}

public void addDP(){
    root_RL.removeView(gBoard_RL);
    dp = new DrawPath(this);
    gBoard_RL.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    gBoard_RL.addView(dp);
    root_RL.addView(gBoard_RL);

}

//-- Get GameBoard info using oGLL
public void getGameBoardNumbers(){
    gBoard_RL.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            NumbersoGLL);   
}

//-- oGLL
OnGlobalLayoutListener NumbersoGLL = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        xScrInt = gBoard_RL.getWidth();
        yScrInt = gBoard_RL.getHeight();

        xScr2Int = gBoard_RL.getWidth()/2;
        yScr2Int = gBoard_RL.getHeight()/2;
        xCenterInt = gBoard_RL.getLeft() + xScr2Int;
        yCenterInt = gBoard_RL.getTop() + yScr2Int;

        xHStr = String.valueOf(xScrInt);
        yWStr = String.valueOf(yScrInt);

        xCenter_FL = (float)xCenterInt;
        yCenter_FL = (float)yCenterInt;

        String xCInt_Str = String.valueOf(xCenterInt);
        String yCInt_Str = String.valueOf(yCenterInt);

        gameScore_TV.setText(xCInt_Str + ", " + yCInt_Str);


    }
};
}
```

Here's the View Class:

```
public class DrawPath extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
Path path = new Path();
private int xC_Int, yC_Int;

class Pt {
    float x, y;

    Pt(float _x, float _y) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }

}

public void setCenterInt(int xC_IInt, int yC_IInt){
    this.xC_Int = xC_IInt;
    this.yC_Int = yC_IInt;
}

Pt[] thePath = { new Pt(xC_Int, yC_Int),
        new Pt(200, 200),
        new Pt(200, 500),
        new Pt(400, 500)
        };

public DrawPath(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(7);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    path.moveTo(thePath[0].x, thePath[0].y);
    for (int i = 1; i < thePath.length; i++) {
        path.lineTo(thePath[i].x, thePath[i].y);
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
}
```

And the Interface Class:

```
public interface GBoardValueSetter {

void passGBCenterIntValuesInterface(int xC_IInt, int yC_IInt);

}
```

Comment: When two classes are completely different in nature yet they need to have same function.

Comment: And this isn't about android but this is about **Java**

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I said similar one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your interface call to your activity, you assign the parameters you get from the call:

```
public void passGBCenterIntValuesInterface(int xC_IInt, int yC_IInt) {
    xC_IInt = xCenterInt; <-- RIGHT THERE
    yC_IInt = yCenterInt; <-- RIGHT THERE
    dp.setCenterInt(xC_IInt, yC_IInt);

}//--- END Interface call
```

xCenterInt and yCenterInt are problably 0